# Plus addressing (address extension), extract only the response message

Tags: php, regex, email, data-extraction

I want to build a messaging system like Facebook (with "plus addressing" function where user can answer directly to the email to post a comment on the website).

"Plus addressing" is not a problem, the problem is to get ONLY the user response in the body message that I got with IMAP and PHP.

So, the option available to me is regex (or something else that I don't know ?)

But even with Regex, how?
How to differentiate the message throughout this nonsense html code.

Here is a screenshot of what I get when I fetch the messages on the server (hightlight strings are the response I want to get).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ixln.jpg
(and a gist too : https://gist.github.com/coolfarmer/9fe4a48e7c98ea5f584f)

In order:

- string 1 : Hotmail response on desktop
- string 2 : Gmail response on desktop
- string 3 : Response from an Android device with her basic email app
- string 4 : Response from an Android device with Gmail App

Thanks in advance for your advices!

Comment: Avoid to post screenshots.